# ubuntu 19.04 hangs with Intel 9th gen processor used in 310chipset motherboard

Tags: 18.04, 19.04

I have following configuration which hangs very often both with Ubuntu 19.04 or 18.04.3 LTS installed in GUI mode. I changed the motherboard with Asus 310 chipset and graphic card with Zotac 1GB ddr3 display card. still the hanging problem exists. I booted with Safegraphics mode too in ubuntu. I also tried with 3 different systems but in vain. can someone suggest what to do?
CONFIGURATION: 
Intel core i5-9th generation 9400 (6core, 2.9ghz)/
Asrock H310CM-HDV motherboard/
16GB DDR-4 2400MHz Crucial RAM/
Asus GT710-SL-1GD5 display card with 1GB DDR-5 video RAM/
1TB toshiba SATA hard disk

Intel Processor URL: https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/134898/intel-core-i5-9400-processor-9m-cache-up-to-4-10-ghz.html)

Asrock Motherboard URL:
https://www.asrock.com/MB/Intel/H310CM-HDV/index.asp

Asus 1GB Display Card URL:
https://www.asus.com/Graphics-Cards/GT710-SL-1GD5/

Comment: Have you tested your ram (with memtest), is it good.

Comment: i checked the RAM which is crucial DDR4-2400MHz and tried with corsair too. the system works fine with win 10 pro.

Comment: you checked the ram with memtest? That finds also processor problems with addressing lines. Comparing to other os doesn't make your random access memory good.

Comment: memtest is passed without any error. I guess it may be incompatible graphic card GT710 may cause this issue. need to find driver support for ubuntu